# How can I set equality condition for Date now and a pre-defined date?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to set the condition below to run Condition1 if `new Date(visitationDate)` is equal to `Date.now()`.

In the frontend the visitationDate come in as `Thu Nov 11 2021 13:52:33 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)` and I convert it with a function to the format `2021-11-11T13:00:00.000Z` before sending it to the backend. I am using the date condition in my question in the backend. I can revert the conversion in the frontend if it will resolve my issue.

This is my current code used in the backend

```
if (new Date(visitationDate) == Date.now()) {
   Condition1
} else {
   Condition2
}
```

My question is how can I run Condition2 if the visitationDate is less than Date.now() or Date.now() is greater than visitationDate. I want to run Condition1 only if visitationDate is the current date or equal to Date.now() in a 24 hour window.

Comment: The hours, minutes and seconds needed to be taken into account?

Comment: Your `if` condition will be true for **a single millisecond**. My guess is that you want a larger window than that. How large? A second? A minute? An hour? A day? Multiple days? Your last paragraph seems to suggest you realize that. What have you tried to address it?

Comment: maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) can help you... `setHours()`

Comment: @T.J. I need a day window for the if condition. Initially I tried using the date as a string but was not having a head way

Comment: @Calvin, that means I'll have to convert the Date.now() to string or will new Date work

Comment: @Wacademy - We need more information in order to help you: 1. What is the exact format you're receiving the date in? 2. Where does the JavaScript code above run (your server? a browser? something else?). 3. Why are you receiving the date as a string? 4. What's converting it to string? 5. When is it being converted? (Was it in the past and something has stored it, or...?) It's important because the solution to your problem depends a **lot** on the details, not least because of timezones, daylight saving time, ...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I updated the question I don't know if it is enough

Comment: @Wacademy - Please answer questions 2 and 5.

Comment: 2. The code run in my backend node.js. I converted in the frontend React form but I can revert the conversation and send the original date to the backend where the code condition is run

Comment: Sadly, another question: What do you mean by "today"? :-) "Today" server time? Or "today" client time? Your client may be on Wednesday when your server is still on Tuesday, for instance. Or do you mean within 12 hours either way of "now"? (All these questions could seem obstructive, but they really aren't meant to be. It's just dates and times across timezones are *complicated*.) Basically, what is the overall goal of the code? What are you trying to find out?

Comment: (And sorry, I should have asked that last question *much* sooner.)

Comment: Thanks @T.J. You really are on point. I want the users to be able to pass Condition1 if their local time is within 12 hours of the current server time. I'm not sure if the server time is different. But the users work hour is usually around 8 hours a day. Give and take 12 hours normalization should be enough. My aim is to allow the user submit the form if their local time is within 12 hours of the server time.

Comment: But aren't we dealing with "now" both on the client and on the server? Within 12 hours of what? It can't be literally "within 12 hours of server time" because that's almost always going to be true. (I think there's a +13 or -13 timezone, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: I was thinking maybe now () will be the basis for the current time either from the server or the user. We are checking the condition against the visitationDate which will vary. But the Date.now should reflect the current local date. Is it not possible to use the local date

Comment: The solution that was posted earlier and deleted with setHours() seems ok for my use case

Answer (score 0):

Based on a previously submitted response that was deleted, I am using the [getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method  to normalize the date and checking if the difference is equal to zero. I tested with the current date and it returns true. When I tested with previous date and future date it returns false. Please note that users of my code have the same local time.

```
let d = new Date(visitationDate);
d.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0)
let now = new Date(); 
now.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0) 

if (now-d == 0) {
   Condition1
} else {
   Condition2
}
```

Comment: Setting to 15:00:00 is really just a random time that has no effect on the date. There is still the issue that parsing the input timestamp results in a different local date due to different offsets. Setting the hours after that doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to compare dates without the time part, so convert the input timestamp to just a date and compare it to the current local date, e.g.

```js
// Convert standard toString format to YYYY-MM-DD without changing the date
function reformatDate(s) {
  // Parse string as UTC+0  
  let d = new Date(s.replace(/GMT\+.*/,'GMT+0000'));
  // Return date only in ISO 8601 format
  return d.toISOString().substring(0,10);
}

// Return date as local YYYY-MM-DD
function formatDate(d) {
  return d.toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
}

let ts = 'Thu Nov 11 2021 13:52:33 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time)';
// Date with some random time
let d = new Date(2021,10,11,23,59,59);
console.log(formatDate(d) + ' : ' +  (reformatDate(ts) == formatDate(d)));

// Compare to today
d = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(d) + ' : ' +  (reformatDate(ts) == formatDate(d)));
```